# Angular - ng-repeat item.Id as Item.Name in Items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have array of objects in `$scope` where an object has `{Id, Name}` keys. On the front side, I generate `select` element on the form where `options` should be names of objects and binded values should be id's of those objects. I want `ng-model` placeholderId of `select` element to have value of item.Id
What I tried is:

```
<select
    name="sequence"
    ng-model="placeholderId"
    required>
<option ng-repeat="item.Id as item.Name in items">{{item.Name}}</option>
```

But got error:

> Error: [ngRepeat:iidexp] '*item*' in '*item* in *collection*' should be an identifier or '(*key*, *value*)' expression, but got

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this.

```html
<select name="sequence" ng-options="item  as item.Name for item in items" ng-model="selectedItem">
```

Now model "selectedItem" is the object. To get value of "Id" you need to do like this in controller.

$scope.selectedItem.Id

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `ng-value`.  rewrite the option tag to look like this:

```
<option ng-repeat="item in items" ng-value="item.Id" >{{item.Name}}</option>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks. And one more question. If I edit form that has select element in it, how can I automatically bind item.Id or Item.Name option for editing object?